# Docker Desktop mixed mode doesn't work anymore

Tags: windows, docker

I'm trying to run linux and windows images using Docker Desktop. The approach is described here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/mixing-windows-and-linux-containers-with-docker-compose/

It was working pretty well with some limitations 3 months ago, but when I try to do it again today, I get no luck. 
I switched to Windows containers and enabled Experimental features. But when I try to use linux image, I've got this error:

```
docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-alpine
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform.
```

What could be a problem? Was this feature removed from docker desktop? Can't find information about it.

My current setup is:

- Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.1098)
- Docker desktop community 2.2.0.4 (43472) stable channel
- Engine: 19.03.8
- Compose: 1.25.4
- Kubernetes: v1.15.5
- Notary: 0.6.1
- Credential Helper: 0.6.3

Comment: see also current issue: https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/79

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like switch "Enable experimental features" is buggy in current version and doesn't really turn on the features. When I added experimental feature to daemon config directly:

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": true
}
```

mixed linux and windows containers started to work as it was before.